# CPU memory frequency specification with multiple channels

Tags: memory, cpu

When manufacturers say that a CPU model supports 2400 MHz and max. 2 channels, what does this mean exactly?

Specifically, does 2400 MHz refer to the maximum effective frequency or to the maximum frequency of a single channel? So if I buy two sticks, should those be 2400 or 1200 MHz at most?

Comment: Are you talking about CPU frequency, or memory? Sounds like memory right? CPU's don't come in "two sticks"

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, I'm wondering what memory to buy, not vice-versa.

Comment: Maybe whatever's cheapest & easiest to return if it breaks

Answer (score 1):

no, its per channel. you can buy 2400 MHZ.
Make sure if 2400 MHZ is supported by your mainboard as well.
Mainboards provide a list of supported Ram modules, it's a good idea to double check if your desired module is on this list. you should update your mainboards firmware. i got one time the problem that my module was on the list, but dit not work on full speed, until i have done the update.